# Using LINQ Where with ArrayList item

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

Someone can help me? How can I get all appsRelatedIds IN arrayList? I work on Api integration and I have the class Apps:

```
 public class Apps
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }
 
        [JsonProperty("active")]
        public bool Active { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        
        [JsonProperty("appsRelatedIds")]
        public ArrayList RelatedId { get; set; }

   }
```

I've created this LINQ and works fine:

```
var appsFiltered = AppsList.Where(x => x.Active == true && x.Description.Contains("Top")).ToList();
```

But I need to get by RelatedIds like and for this response the API returns only ids related:

```
int relatedId = 5;  
var appsFiltered = AppsList.Where(x => x.Active == true && x.RelatedId.Contains(relatedId).ToList();
```

Example Data:

1. line1 - Id 1234 Active=true Description='Top Gun' RelatedId= [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
2. line2 - Id 12345 Active=true Description='Top Gun'  Maverick' RelatedId= [ 1, 3, 4, 5 ]
3. line3 - Id 123456 Active=true
   Description='Transformers' RelatedId=[ 7,8,9]

In this case I need appsFiltered with line1 and line2 because relatedId parameter 5 is inside RelatedId ArrayList.

I tried to use a LINQ

Comment: And what is your problem? Your LINQ should work. It just lacks a close parenthesis char: `var appsFilterd = appsList.Where(x => x.Active == true && x.RelatedId.Contains(relatedId));`

Comment: Step 1. Don't use `ArrayList`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=net-7.0#remarks

Comment: Echoing @Jodrell: Look at the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist.  Then search for that big blue _Remarks_ box where it says: _"We don't recommend that you use the `ArrayList` class for new development. Instead, we recommend that you use the generic `List<T>` class. The `ArrayList` class is designed to hold heterogeneous collections of objects. However, it does not always offer the best performance. Instead, we recommend the following ..."_.  `ArrayList` hasn't been useful since 2005!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why using ArrayList instead of List?
[ArrayList are usually slow in performance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=net-7.0#remarks)

```
var appsFiltered = AppsList.Where(x => x.Active == true && x.RelatedId.Any(a=> a == relatedId).ToList();
```

Comment: I Changed to:
 public IList RelatedId { get; set; }
When I add x.RelatedId.Any I give one exception: "IList does not contain definition to .Any" and "ArrayList does not contain definition to Any".

Code: var appsFiltered = AppsList.Where(x => x.Active == true && x.RelatedId.Any(c=> c == relatedId).ToList();

Comment: @Lucas. RelatedId should be declared as List<int> not IList.